# Yoast title problem with ACF with relation on CPT

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, yoast

I have two custom post type: one is some kind of parent and the other is like a group of children that I obtain through a relation in ACF.

It happens that Yoast composes the title for children using the title of the parent and there is no way to change it until I remove all the associations with the parent.

Has it happen to someone other than me? is there a solution?

**EDIT**
There is a "first level" CPT (call it "parent").

By an ACF relation I can associate a second CPT (call it "children")

So the structure is:

```
--parent
  -- children 1
  -- children 2
  -- children 3
```

I've set the metatitle for parent suppose it is "parent title" and a metatitle structure for children.
It happens that the childrens have the parent metatitle and it is not possibile to change it until I delete the relation between the two levels.

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Can you elaboreate more, can you show us some screenshots, what you want to accomplish

Comment: question edited